# How to make one CSS file more !important than others

Tags: css, reactjs, import, sass

I am on a react project I have a lot of SCSS files I want to make one SCSS for medias and it should overwrite any other SCSS how to do that because in react it is a bit different from simple HTML CSS and I can't import one file the last so that it could be the most important

Comment: please show us how you have used your scss files.

Comment: Oh they are a lot about 10 components each with it's scss and a lot of !important-s in them so I just need one file even with all !importants that would be imported the last and overwrite them all for media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you mean, you can clear that mess easily, just replace all media-s to one seperate file like `media.scss`
And order them from highest (widest) screen to lowest if something will blow in your site just add `!important` to all of the medias and you can add anything there and it will be the most important
P.S. you don't need to manually add !important just search all `;` -s and replace with `!important;` then replace `!important!important` with `!important` that would clear everything

Answer (score 2):

create like this.

make a scss file somewhere. e.g overWriteKiller.scss

in `overWriteKiller.scss` white your codes

Implementation. example component

```
import otherScss from 'otherScss.scss';

import overWriteKiller from 'overWriteKiller/overWriteKiller.scss';

// here is your component's code going
```

point is that file has to be import at the very last.

Comment: That's a good answer so I voted it up, but I have a lot of SCSS files so I am searching for something that wouldn't change them just adding somewhere in the end

Comment: please share one of your code. so that i can come up with a solution